# Windows Phone Application Deployment error 0x89731812

Tags: windows-phone-7

When I try to deploy my XAP to the Windows Phone, I get the "error 0x89731812" message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your device has a locked screen. Unfortunately, this is not documented anywhere, but there is a [discussion](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=29293497#post29293497) with some hints on page 3.

1. Turn on your phone (if it isn't already)
2. Slide open
3. Type your password to unlock

Retry the deployment after unlocking your screen.

EDIT: My bad (well, that of my search engine). They are documented [here](http://phone7.wordpress.com/2010/12/01/wp7-deployment-error-codes-explained/). Thanks keyboardP!

Comment: For future reference, I've documented what the error codes mean  here- http://phone7.wordpress.com/2010/12/01/wp7-deployment-error-codes-explained/

Answer (score 0):

As I Stumbled upon this old thread I might have found a solution for this Error code.

I've had the same message as I found out that my device wasn't recognised properly in device manager. 
Did some research and saw that the driver wasn't picking the right USB-port as it was registered to one of the other usb ports.

After inserting the Phone to the first USB port where it was registered the Initial first time everything went ok!

Answer (score 0):

If your phone charge is very low, it won't deploy the app too.
To deploy you must:
1.Connect your wp7 phone
2.Open Zune
3.Open the deployer
4.unlock your phone (As said before)
5.Deploy

It requires an unlocked phone (without restrictions) or an Interop Unlocked Phone, and the phone mustn't have low charge.