# Error 0x80131501 and error 0x89731812 when launching Windows Phone Project in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-phone-8

When I want to launch any Windows Phone project in Visual-Studio 2012 with the Windows Phone emulator, I get the following errors: `0x80131501`, and `0x89731812`.

How do I fix these errors?

Comment: Can you share the full text of the error message?

Comment: I just have "Erreur 1 0x80131501" and a alert window with "0x89731812"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows Phone Application Deployment error 0x89731812](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11648442/windows-phone-application-deployment-error-0x89731812)

Comment: I don't have a windows phone i use a emulator.

Comment: The emulator works fine but the project can't be opened into it...

Comment: Please help me :( I have an exam tomorrow, I'm going to present my mobile app but this error block me...

Comment: Take a look over [here](http://phone7.wordpress.com/2010/12/01/wp7-deployment-error-codes-explained/) for the details.