# DEP0001 : Unexpected Error: -1988945906 while deploying Windows UWP app to phone

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, win-universal-app, windows-10

Exact error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error     DEP0001 : Unexpected Error: -1988945906 TestApp

What does it mean? It seems it isn't problem with application, it works OK on PC.

Version of OS: 1511, Windows 10 for phones 10.0.10586.164

Comment: Convert the error number to hex and you'll end up with "Connection to device failed. Please ensure the phone is connected and the not on the lock screen" and [this Q+A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11648442/windows-phone-application-deployment-error-0x89731812).

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I've experienced the same problem after updating Visual Studio community to Update 2. Typing in CMD (under admin rights) the following command solved my issue:

```
net start IpOverUsbSvc
```

Thanks to Agrgg for a good tip ;)

Comment: it starts IpOverUsbSvc service on your PC. I think this service is responsible for maintaining connection with your device :)

Comment: I already have IpOverUsbSvc working, still same problem. Any idea?

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks

Comment: I had the same problem. Ones I solved the error by starting the mentioned service. But after a while the error re-occured. The service is still up and running, a restart wont work at all. The unexpected error is back. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Worked for me. Strange caz It was working fine and suddenly this happened

Comment: that works, Thanks, it was running fine but when i run WMware it suddenly show cant deploy to device

Comment: Had this problem on and off for weeks - usually about 20 restarts would eventually solve it - I guess the restart would eventually kickstart IpOverUsbService - now I know how to do it without restarting!

Comment: If you have Windows 10 and you face this problem because there's no such service, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53522760/1830814

Answer (score 9):

This kind of error happens very randomly and usually it means there was an issue during the deployment of the app. Things to check:

- Developer mode is correctly enabled on phone
- Uninstall the app from phone, rebuild solution and then try debug again
- Check that the architecture for all projects is set accordingly (ARM for debugging on real device)
- Sometimes the VS debugger hangs up, so closing VS and kill from Task Manager all VS processes that are eventually running and restart VS may also help.

Comment: Everything seems to be set up correctly. How can I check whether Visual Studio sees my device? Maybe it's a problem with VS?

Comment: Yes, it may be a problem with VS, for that I suggested you to try to restart it after kill all processes related to VS. Or even a system reboot will be fine.
If you open a command line to this path:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x86\
and launch **WinAppDeployCmd** _devices_ you can see if your device is recognized and ready to receive a deployed package. You can also try to deploy your app using the _install_ command.

Comment: System reboot didn't help. WinAppDeployCmd doesn't see any devices (phone itself is connected to PC, I can browse through files using Windows File Explorer).

Comment: Where can I found Windows Universal App instalation file in my project? I thought that extension of those files is *.appx, but I can't find it. If I can't test it thorugh Visual Studio, I will run it manually.

Comment: IpOverUsbSvc was already working for me, uninstalling my app worked.

Comment: Same here @AdrianK, had to uninstall the app. Worked fine afterwards. Nothing else worked. Rebooted both devices, cleaned solution, restarted that service.

Comment: Sorted my problem. Uninstalling seems to sort it. Cheers!

Answer (score 5):

I had the same error with deploying onto Windows Phone 8.1 device. In my case the problem was in Windows Phone IP over USB Transport (IpOverUsbSvc) service, which wasn't running. The deployment error disappeared after I'd started the service manually.

Comment: I had the same problem. Ones I solved the error by starting the mentioned service. But after a while the error re-occured. The service is still up and running, a restart wont work at all. The unexpected error is back. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.

"net start IpOverUsbSvc" didn't worked for me (throws Access is denied Exception).

I have followed following steps to fix.

1. Start Run (Windows+R), Type: services.msc
2. Start/Restart Windows phone IP over USB Transport.

[image: Windows Services window]

Answer (score 1):

For the RPi, I have RPi3 with WIOT (build 14376) this error happens after failed deployment. Just restart VS and it'll deploy ok.

Answer (score 1):

After trying some of the answers already provided and nothing worked, I fixed the error by simply **restarting the phone**. 
After that the error was gone for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and found that in my case it was occurring while the phone was downloading system updates in the background.
App updates/installations from the app Store were also prevented from downloading/installing.

After the update had finished, all was back to working again.

As Windows Phone 10 doesn't seem to make it obvious that it's downloading updates, maybe worth checking this out if you hit this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, solution is here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/apps/jj863509(v=vs.105).aspx
Look at Checking BIOS settings required by Hyper-V for Data Execution Prevention. You must select "Turn on DEP for all programs and services except those i select" and in my case application deploys successfully.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was as simple as unlocking the phone so that the computer would have access to it.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue as well. None of the answers helped me. IpOverUsbSvc was up and runing, phone reset, system reboot, nothing...
The issue was fixed after a Visual Studio "repair": control panel -> Programs and features -> select VS2015 -> Repair

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar error.

The reason the error occurred for me was because I forgot to add the new splash images in assets after deleting the old ones.

The solution was to add the images. To get the correct image names and sizes, I used [this](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2016/02/15/uwp-tile-generator-extension-for-visual-studio/#F6HcVV8093csZtRE.97) extension for visual studio.

Answer (score 0):

## For Windows 10 (desktop) users

I faced this problem after I uninstalled Windows 10 SDK. It deleted the `IpOverUsbSvc` service from the system.

### Solution

1. Download the [Windows 10 SDK .iso installer](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkID=2033686)
2. Inside it there is `Installers` folder.
3. Find `Windows IP Over USB-x86_en-us.msi`. Install it. (Don't worry if there is no setup window, it installs fast and silently).
4. I didn't even have to reboot VS2015, it just worked.
5. Check if the `IpOverUsbSvc` service is running

   - Open a Powershell prompt and type `Get-Service -Name *USB*`
   - Or go to the Services window. There you should see the IpOverUsbSvc running.

Answer (score -1):

So, I think I get the trick. After plugged in your Windows Mobile device, Windows App Deploy can see W10M device, but once your device goes to lock screen, WPD can not detect it anymore.

You should to plug out and plugin again, with screen unlocked, to make it detectable. *(I'm not a really English speaker).*