# Windows-10 Mobile DEP0001 : Unexpected Error: -1988945906

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2015, arm, windows-10-universal

Unable to deploy uwp app on mobile device. I am trying to deploy my app on my Windows 10 mobile device (Lumia 950). I get this error:

> DEP0001 : Unexpected Error: -1988945906

This was working well until yesterday. Today morning when MS forced me to update to **VS-2015 Update 2**. After I updated my VS I started to hit this error. 
I currently have **Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2015 Version Version 14.0.25123.00 Update 2**

Based on some suggestion on the internet, I tried deleting any previously installed version of my app on device before re-installing, but I still see the error.

Comment: You can find solution from [DEP0001 : Unexpected Error: -1988945906 while deploying Windows UWP app to phone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36384375/dep0001-unexpected-error-1988945906-while-deploying-windows-uwp-app-to-phone)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks @ARH for pointing me to the solution.

For the benefit of everyone who gets redirected here, the solution is to open Windows Command Prompt in admin mode and run

> net start IpOverUsbSvc

Comment: I had the same problem. Ones I solved the error by starting the mentioned service. But after a while the error re-occured. The service is still up and running, a restart wont work at all. The unexpected error is back. Any other suggestions?