# DEP0001 : Unexpected Error: -2147023436 While deploying Universal Windows App to Windows 10 Mobile

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2015, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

**The Error Message**

> Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error
>   DEP0001 : Unexpected Error: -2147023436

[image]

**What I Did**

I installed xamarin in my Visual Studio 2015 and while installation it also took in all the latest updates. And from then on I started facing errors, one after another. Initial errors were all related to *somehow Visual Studio Update 2 deleted deleting the service named **IpOverUsbSvc***

But I have managed to solve the problem my downloading the latest Windows 10 SDK and running **Windows IP Over USB-x86_en-us.msi** installer.

So, [this SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36384375/dep0001-unexpected-error-1988945906-while-deploying-windows-uwp-app-to-phone) is not my issue, as my IpOverUsbSvc is now up and running.

But now I am facing this new issue and no help is available on google. So I am putting it up here, so that as soon as anyone gets a work around others also get the help.

My code is running fine on local machine. But only facing this error when trying to deploy it on phone. This is a Universal Windows App built with Cordova.

**And this is my Visual Studio Configuration**

[image]

Everything was working fine till before this update.

Any idea? Anyone?

[I also find no way to revert this update. My only option now seems like uninstalling and reinstalling the whole VS2015] :P

**EDIT / UPDATE 1**

I turned all radio button options related to USB and network discovery (inside security) on my phone. Now the error has become,

> DEP6701 : Bootstrapping failed with unexpected error: 'The system
>   cannot find the path specified 'Bin\ARM\dbghelp.dll'

Looks like something has gone missing from somewhere due to that last update.

Comment: -2147023436 = FFFFFFFF800705B4 = ERROR_TIMEOUT . is your device configured to apply sideloading/deploying apps?

Comment: Good point. Does upgrading my mobile from 8.1 to 10 somehow messed with its configuration / registration? I will have to check. I tried so many things, but this did not occur to me. Good point. Thanks. I will check it now.

Comment: open settings app, go to security -> "for developers" and enable dev mode and try again

Comment: Also, please tell me how *-2147023436* became  *FFFFFFFF800705B4*  and then *ERROR_TIMEOUT* ? @magicandre1981

Comment: I used calc to convert the value from dec to hex and now used err.exe from Win7 SDK to show what the code means

Comment: Checked. Developer mode was on. But other USB options like Device Discovery etc were Off. Turned all of them On. Now I will try again....

Comment: Updated the question with current result. I will now try to find and put that .dll in its place. [The entire error message changed. Should I ask in a new question? @magicandre1981 ]

Comment: this is a debugger DLL to load symbols. it is art of the Windows Performacne Toolkit. After setup of WPT (part of Win10 SDK), get the WPTarm-arm_en-us.msi from **C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Windows Performance Toolkit\Redistributables** and do admin install (http://www.wikihow.com/Create-an-Administrative-Installation-Point-for-Installing-Entrust-Security-Provider-for-Windows) to get the DLL

Comment: Tried. Failed. So restarted, again tried, again failed :( I guess, I will uninstall and the reinstall the entire VS2015 :P

Comment: hm, does the reinstall fixes it?

Comment: Before uninstalling, I am going thru all the other options like, repair, modify... Repair didn't help... Now modifying... Will let you know... :)

Comment: If you try to deploy a Windows Universal JS project do you have the same error?

Comment: Please wait till 20th. I will answer all of you. Currently continuing development on a different machine. Will resume back to the machine in Question on 20th June.

Comment: Any news about this?

Comment: My answer was deleted by @Martijn Pieters  .. since another question with the same problema answered by me exists. Really don't understand why I can't answer both questions if are equivalent. Well yesterday was released 10.0.14367 build, it solves this problema.

Comment: What worked for me was simply reboot the device.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, restart the device and problem solved